# How to extend a Breeze Controller's response with non-model data?

Tags: entity-framework, odata, breeze, asp.net-web-api2, dto

I have a Web API 2 project with Microsoft.Data.Odata 5.6, Breeze.WebApi2 1.5 and EF6.

Breeze works amazingly well using `$select` and `$expand` syntax to obtain the details of my queries through navigational properties.

The one issue that I've been fighting with is on how to include some external data to the resulting entities, once the odata queries have been effectively resolved.

My approach so far has consisted in extending BreezeQueryableAtribute and trying to piggyback the result, so that I can inject my ad-hoc data before sending it to the client.

With a process somewhat similar to the one followed by the BreezeQueryable attribute itself

https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.server.net/blob/master/Breeze.WebApi2/BreezeQueryableAttribute.cs

However, I am unable to parse the result from the response. Which seems to be returned as an anonymous Breeze.ContextProvider.DynamicTypeBase that fails to cast back to IQuerable, e.g.

```
public class CustomBreezeQueryable :BreezeQueryableAttribute 
{

public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
{
    var response = actionExecutedContext.Response;

    //some validation code removed for clarity
    base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);

    if (!response.TryGetContentValue(out responseObject))
    {
        return;
    }
    var queryResult = responseObject as IQueryable<MyEntityType>;

    //queryResult is null!

    //apply transforms to resulting entities
    //var dtos = ....

    actionExecutedContext.Response = actionExecutedContext.Request
            .CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, dtos.AsQueryable());
}}
```

An interesting thing is that I can actually inspect the results of the query through the VS "locals" window and browse through the internal properties of the result set.
So as far as Breeze goes, everything is working as expected, but I haven't found an easy way to extend the results produced.

[image: entity inspection]

My guess is that the wrapping and formatting produced by this internal Breeze call `queryHelper.WrapResult(request, response, queryResult);` is what's stopping me from using IQueryable.

Any ideas on how I could parse this Breeze.ContextProvider.DynamicTypebase back to my standard Entity?
Or maybe an entirely different approach?

Thanks,

Jaume